# Python Skip Multiple Steps in Loop

Tags: python, loops

Suppose I have a a loop as such:

```
for i in range(0,100):
    if (condition):
    X
```

and I want the loop, in the event of the conditional being true, not to skip to the next iteration of the loop, but to skip several iterations forward. i.e. It is as if I want not just one '**continue**' statement, but several.

For example, suppose my loop is on **i=57**. The conditional is true. I want it to then skip 58, 59, 60, 61, and go to process i=62. The conditional there is false, and it then goes to process 63.

Is there any way to implement this in a standard *for loop*?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps use a while loop:

```
x = 0
while x < 100:
    if condition(x):
        x += 5
    else:
        x += 1
```

Comment: I just thought of that! Thanks, nonetheless!

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, the solution is simple! I just need to use a *while loop* and increment it manually.

Comment: 20 second right after my post :p. Well, congrats in getting it working! :)

Answer (score 1):

If the range you are processing over is indeed static, you would be better served by a while block. That way you have arbitrary control over the index being used.